# convert dataframe from wide layout to SQL-style slim layout

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert a dataframe like this:

```
          a         b         c
0  1.067683 -1.110463  0.208670
1 -1.321405  0.368915 -1.055342
2 -0.807333  0.082980 -0.873361
```

into

```
    det     value
0     a  1.067683
1     a -1.321405
2     a -0.807333
3     b -1.110463
4     b  0.368915
5     b  0.082980
6     b  0.082980
7     c  0.208670
8     c -1.055342
9     c -0.873361
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt):

```
In [11]: from pandas.core.reshape import melt

In [12]: melt(df)
Out[12]:
  variable     value
0        a  1.067683
1        a -1.321405
2        a -0.807333
3        b -1.110463
4        b  0.368915
5        b  0.082980
6        c  0.208670
7        c -1.055342
8        c -0.873361
```

Comment: also there as `pd.melt` :)

Comment: @AndyHayden maybe this is something for the cookbook? I could imagine it has quite a use case?